# asp.net core didn't binding value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

The input control didn't show the binding values.
Here is the reproduce steps:

1. open vs2019, and choose "ASP.NET Core Web App(Model-View-Controller)" template.
2. Leave the project name as default: WebApplication1.
3. choose Target Framework: .NET 5.0, "None" Authentication Type.
4. Use this code for Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddSession(options => { options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Error}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

5. Add two models

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    [Serializable]
    public class QueryInfoModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Work Number")]
        public string WorkNum { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    [Serializable]
    public class StaffInfoModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Work Number")]
        public string workNum { get; set; }
    }
}
```

6. Modify the Index.cshtml

```
@model StaffInfoModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<div class="text-center">
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="InputInfo" method="post" class="form-horizontal col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
        @*工号*@
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label asp-for="workNum" class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="workNum" class="form-control col-sm-4" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

7. Add Query.cshtml

```
@model QueryInfoModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Query Page";
}
<div class="text-center">
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Query" method="post" class="form-horizontal col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label asp-for="WorkNum" class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="WorkNum" class="form-control col-sm-4" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="WorkNum" class="text-danger  col-sm-offset-3"></span>

        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
            <input type="submit" value="query" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-4" />
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

8. And this is the HomeController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Query()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Query(QueryInfoModel model)
        {
            StaffInfoModel staff = new StaffInfoModel();
            staff.workNum = "1010101010";

            Debug.WriteLine(staff.workNum);

            return View("Index", staff);
        }
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            StaffInfoModel staff = new StaffInfoModel();
            staff.workNum = "1010101010";

            return View("Index", staff);
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

9. At last, Modify the navbar in the _layout.cshtml

```
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Query">Query</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Now, run the application.
When Press the Privacy, you can see there is a string in the textbox.
But when click the query button in the Query page, there is no content in the textbox. And the confusion thing is when you input some text in the query textbox, and then click the query button, you will see the inputed text in the textbox. It seems the binding is failed. But I know the binding didn't failed, because when click the privacy menu, the text 1010101010 is showing. So why the value cannot be shown correctly when click the Query button in the query page?

Comment: There are two ways to workaround this issue: 1. set the value explicitly: ```<input type="text" asp-for="workNum" class="form-control col-sm-4" value="@Model.workNum" /> ``` 2. change the property name of StaffInfoModel, for example,  from workNum to workNum1, just change the case of the property name is not useful.

Comment: Because you pass the value by model, but you didn't use it at all. You can use it by "string valuPassed = model.WorkNum;" or "Debug.WriteLine(model.workNum);"

Comment: Hi there, if I didn't use it at all, why when I click on Privacy menu, the text 1010101010 is shown?

Comment: I made a project the same as you. As you said controller reacts weirdly.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong Model in **Query.cshtml**.
You have passed an object from **StaffInfoModel**. You must change it to **StaffInfoModel** so change the model in your **Query.cshtml** like this:

```
@model StaffInfoModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Query Page";
}
<div class="text-center">
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Query" method="post" class="form-horizontal col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label asp-for="WorkNum" class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="WorkNum" class="form-control col-sm-4" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="WorkNum" class="text-danger  col-sm-offset-3"></span>

        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
            <input type="submit" value="query" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-4" />
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You may misunderstood me. My question is "when you input some text in the query textbox, and then click the query button, you will see the inputed text in the textbox rather than the fixed string 1010101010 which I explicitly assigned in the controller."

Comment: Use  Model staff to render the page Index, the textbox in the index page should show the workNum property value of staff. I had set the workNum to the fixed string 1010101010, so whatever you inputed in the textbox in the query page, the index page should always show the fixed string 1010101010. But the fact is the index page always show the text in the query page.